# Why would one run cat|bash before copying/pasting into a terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, scripting

I've seen someone running `cat|bash` before pasting commands from the clipboard into a terminal.

**bash** executes commands in bash I do not know why do we need `cat` here and `|(pipe)`.

What useful effects does this practice have?

Comment: ...generally, there are other/better ways to get input into a shell on stdin while asserting that stdin isn't a TTY. `bash <<'EOF'` will do the job, f/e. with no need for `cat` -- as a heredoc is presented as a file, not a TTY. So will `curl | bash`, or `bash < inputfile`, or pretty much any other useful case I can think of.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the command, It was my colleague who executed a bunch of command in the terminal, it will be executed if do just copy and paste directly into terminal but he did `cat|bash` before pasting those set of commands.

Comment: That clarifies the question a lot! Personally, I'd run `bash <<'EOF"` instead, and then type `EOF` after the paste, but the approaches generally accomplish about the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

> It was my colleague who executed a bunch of command in the terminal, [...] he did `cat|bash` before pasting those set of commands

He likely this to stop Bash from interpreting anything in the commands as editing input, to override any special keybindings and aliases he's set up, and/or to prevent commands from consuming the command stream as input.

Consider this command with two embedded tab characters:

```
    if true
    then
        echo "yup"
    fi
```

Here's what happens when you paste it into a shell (because the tab characters trigger tab completion in interactive input):

```
$ if true
> then
>
Display all 2600 possibilities? (y or n)
!                                   grub-mkfont                         pnmmontage
./                                  grub-mkimage                        pnmnlfilt
:                                   grub-mklayout                       pnmnoraw
```

And here's a snippet that involves `ssh`:

```
ssh localhost uptime
echo "Finished"
```

When you paste it into a shell, the second command gets consumed as input by `ssh`, so you get this:

```
$ ssh localhost uptime
 09:53:40 up 28 days, 18:33, 25 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.01, 0.00
```

In both cases, pasting into `cat | bash` instead will cause the commands to run as-is.

Answer (score 1):

This reads commands from the terminal and executes them in `bash`. It's similar to just running `bash` by itself, except that when bash's standard input is a terminal it runs interactively by default -- it displays prompts, performs input editing, enable aliases, performs job control, etc. This will run non-interactively, so it will just execute the commands as if they were in a script.

I'm not sure *why* someone would want to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Barman . One reason I can see is that. Just copy pasting set of commands get stored in `history` but doing `cat|bash` is not storing that command into history as well not switching by default shell (zsh) to bash on bash command

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other good answers given here (tab completion, ssh/ptty), cat|bash will not let the pasted commands change the environment of the *current* shell.

For example, if the copy-n-paste'd commands are:

```
PATH=/some/place/odd:$PATH
somecommand some args
```

The the PATH is unchanged after the shell in cat|bash exits after running somecommand.