# Tab-indented if statement fails on command line but works in bash script

Tags: bash, command-line

I write my scripts in a text editor using tabs for indentation as it is easier to type 1 `Tab` than 4 `Space`. However, I just drove myself nuts trying to figure out why the `if` statement below, which works in my `bash` script, fails to work on the command line:

```
dirs=(HIC11490 HIC11493 HIC11494)
for i in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then 
        echo $i exists; 
    else 
        echo $i does not exist;
    fi
done
```

Specifically, it lists all of the files in the working directory:

```
$ nums=(HIC11490 HIC11493 HIC11494)
$ for i in "${nums[@]}"; do
> if [ -d "$i" ]; then
>
Display all 13526 possibilities? (y or n)
14295291/                                    HIC3958/
AG25/                                        HIC3959/
AG36/                                        HIC3969/
AG48_Aleksei/                                HIC397/
BGS-11/                                      HIC3970/
BSCC/                                        HIC3971/
  .                                            .
  .                                            .
  .                                            .
DNA128/                                      HIC4465/
DNA129/                                      HIC4466/
> ot exist;
> fi
> done
-bash: ot: command not found
-bash: ot: command not found
-bash: ot: command not found
```

Turns out, the tabs were the problem, and the code works from the command line if they are replaced with spaces.

Are there any other characters that behave differently in `bash` scripts than on the command line that I should be aware of? Thanks.

Comment: `fails to work` - How does it fail? What does it mean to "fail to work"? Does it print a syntax error? Does it print nothing? Does it print something? Does it exit with exit status?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I've included the output. It appears to print out all the directories in the current working directory.

Comment: Do you know what `tab` does on command line? Like you do `gre<tab>` and the `p` part is filled for you?

Comment: That's it! I've only ever used tab to autocomplete file/directory names. I didn't know it could be used for commands. Also, notice that the single `tab` before `for` didn't cause a problem; I just tested typing `gre<tab><tab>` at the command line, and it printed a list of all commands that start with `gre`, and when I type `if [ -d "$i" ]; then<tab>tab>` it lists all the files and directories in my current working directory.

Comment: @KamilCuk, post that as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Why would one run cat|bash before copying/pasting into a terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901154/why-would-one-run-catbash-before-copying-pasting-into-a-terminal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending `tab` to bash triggers autocompletion. Two `tab` characters trigger showing all possible completions. Bash sees that you started typing `for i in "${nums[@]}"; do` and then two `tab` trigger autocompletion. In this case because no match to a registered completion are found, most autocompletion scripts then list all files in the current directory.  If the list is longer then some length, a `Display all 13526 possibilities?` question is displayed. Then characters are read from the input to answer the `Display all 13526 possibilities? (y or n)` part (ie. the `echo` will be passed as an answer to this question...) and the script falls apart.

This is all configurable. Bash uses [GNU readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library for reading what you type and the library handles (parts) of autocompletion.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the second part of your question (since the first has been answered already by KamilCuk), other characters which you should be aware of, are `#` and `!`.

In scripts (non-interactive shells), a `#` introduces a comment, while in an interactive shell, you can configure, whether or not this is the case, or whether a hash should be treated as valid character at the start of a command. This is controlled by the *interactive_comments* setting of `shopt`.

In interactive shells, `!` introduces history substitution (i.e. `!$` is replaced by the last argument of the most recent command). This substitution does not occur in a bash script.

Comment: That explains why #-commented lines that I cut-and-paste from the text editor caused problems. Thanks